# aref links opening in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am trying to create webpage with menus and each menu item is separate html page. While clicking the menu items they open up in the separate page(hiding the menu) which don't want as the user should be able to click on other menu they should open up in same page with menu item being displayed all time. I tried several thing but cant establish it. 
Below is the html :

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>gurukul_admin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gurukul_admin.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="iframe.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    <iframe width = "1120" class = "iframe" height = "900" style="float:right" name="admission"></iframe>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="left-menu">
      <div class="logo"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
        <div>Pure CSS Accordion Nav</div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion">

      <div class="section">
          <input type="radio" name="accordion-1" id="section-1" checked="checked"/>
          <label for="section-1"><span>Dashboard</span></label>
        </div>

        <div class="section">
          <input type="radio" name="accordion-1" id="section-2" value="toggle"/>
          <label for="section-2"><span>Admissions</span></label>
          <div class="content">
            <ul>
              <li><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i><span><a href="admission_dec.html" target="_self">Application Decision</a></span></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-share"></i><span><a href="admission_tte.html" target="_self">Enrol/Reject</a></span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
          <input type="radio" name="accordion-1" id="section-3" value="toggle"/>
          <label for="section-3"> <span>Enrolment</span></label>
          <div class="content">
            <ul>
              <li><i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span>Section Allocation</span></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-group"></i><span>Change Section</span></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i><span>Exam Allocation</span></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i><span><a href="feeallocation.html" target="_self">Fee Allocation</a></span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
          <input type="radio" name="accordion-1" id="section-4" value="toggle"/>
          <label for="section-4"> <span>Administration</span></label>
          <div class="content">
            <ul>
              <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span><a target="_self" href="acadmgmt.html" >Academic Year</a></span></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span><a href="classmgmt1.html" target="_self">Class Codes</a></span></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span><a href="sectmgmt.html" target="_self">Section Codes</a></span></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span><a href="submgmt.html" target="_self">Subject Codes</a></span></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span><a href="feemgmt.html" target="_self">Fee Category/Codes</a></span></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span><a href="assessmgmt.html" target="_self">Assessment Codes</a></span></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span><a href="usermgmt.html" target="_self">System Users</a></span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
          <input type="radio" name="accordion-1" id="section-5" value="toggle"/>
          <label for="section-5"> <span>Staff Management</span></label>
          <div class="content">
            <ul>
              <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span><a href="addstaff.html" target="_self">Add New Staff</a></span></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i><span><a href="viewstaff.html" target="_self">Class Codes</a></span></li>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is css

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400,700);
@import url(http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css);
.accordion {
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
}
.accordion .section {
  width: 100%;
}
.accordion .section input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}
.accordion .section input[type='radio']:checked + label {
  background: #363636;
}
.accordion .section input[type='radio']:checked + label:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 3px solid #21CCFC;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.accordion .section input[type='radio']:checked ~ .content {
  max-height: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.accordion .section label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: table;
  background: #222;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.accordion .section label:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #363636;
}
.accordion .section label:hover {
  background: #363636;
}
.accordion .section label span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.accordion .section:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #363636;
}
.accordion .section .content {
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #1ABC9C;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.left-menu {
  background: #222;
  width: 210px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.accordion {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.accordion .section .content {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.accordion .section input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}
.accordion .section input[type='radio']:checked ~ .content {
  padding: 15px;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  padding: 10px;
}
ul li i {
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li:hover i {
  color: #21CCFC;
}

.logo {
  padding: 30px 10px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.logo i {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #21CCFC;
}
```

- I tried with iframe but alignment changes on different screen size it looks horrible *

Iframe css

```
iframe {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;

  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;

  border: none;
  background-color:#1ABC9C; 
  scrolling="no";
}
a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: #363636;
    color: white; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #363636;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: You should use AJAX

Comment: @pol I am new to ajax can you provide more detail to me on this?

Comment: The basic principal is that when the user clicks on a link, he sends a request to the server. The server processes it and returns some data, which can change only a specific area on the page (depends on how you implement it). Facebook uses ajax btw.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how familiar you with JQuery, but this might be helpful: 
I would write a script, that would change the iframe src value to the corresponding url of the page on click.
In your case it would look something like this:

script.js

```
$("a").click(function(event, target){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.target);
  $("#myiframe").attr("src", $(event.target).attr("href"));
});
```

Instead of a you can assign classes to the links in your menu, and put them in the code instead of "a".
In your index.html

```
<div>
    <iframe src="anyurl.com" id="myiframe"></iframe> 
</div>
```

It is important that you provide an id to your iframe to call it properly from the script.
Delete target attribute from your menu links, as they are not necessary anymore.

Comment: I know about jquery and thought about this. Howwever I am confused wihich jquery library amd does div element need to be used instead of aref?

Comment: The jquery I used is: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: What do you mean by aref?

Comment: Please, check my jsFiddle example, it should help you! https://jsfiddle.net/ed7vd3uc/

Comment: I am using aref to reference additional page which should open in iframe

Comment: yes I did but didnt open the html page which I have stored in my web directory

Answer (score 0):

After lot of deliberation and hits and misses I eventually found out that I had to position my iframe under  and position it accordingly